# How to install steamcmd on heroku?

Tags: heroku, steam

## I was searching in google, there and on heroku support.

I think only 1 way to do it is by instaling it by sudo, but on heroku i dont have sudo.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. What are you trying to accomplish? Surely Steam itself won't run on Heroku.

Comment: Yes, Freezi, you need will need sudo to install Steam, to fix some problems and add 32-bit architecture if it's a 64-bit machine. What are you looking to do with the client remotely? @Chris It's totally possible to run Steam on a remote server, even a headless one. It's really not practical except for coding projects though, unless it's somehow possible to use it for SteamLink, I guess.

Comment: @l3l_aze, Heroku isn't a general purpose "remote server". It's a platform as a service application host that runs a very specialized environment. For example, you can't just `sudo apt install` things, and you can't persistently write to the local filesystem. I stand by my comment, and we can't help without more information from OP.

Comment: Yes, I know real sudo isn't possible (but found a fakesu that uses chroot jail), and understand/agree with you that Heroku won't be the easiest/best place for this.

Comment: ...it's not about not having `sudo` access and working around that with other tools. It's that Heroku _is containerized_. You need a build process that generates an application slug, and after that slug is built you can't modify the filesystem in a reliable way.

Comment: Ok thank u all for help <3